# Wordpress Multiple Category Descriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do you enable multiple `category_description();` on wordpress category description pages? What I have been able to find out is that you can only have one on a category page. I may be wrong, that's why I'm here :)

[image: Default category descrription]

The codex `https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description` doesn't seem to say anything about enabling multiple category_descriptions for categories.

I would really love to have one description at the top (before the content), and one description below (after the content) in the front end. Trying to use this on a woocommerce product category page. Most hosted ecommerce platforms have this description above and below implemented. Of course, this will be useful for all post types as well. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an extra field hook. Have a look at [this](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-category-extra-fields/).